# Count a certain value for each country

Tags: python, pandas

I am attempting to do a Excel `countif` function with `pandas` but hitting a roadblock in doing so.

I have this `dataframe`. I need to count the `YES` for each country quarter-wise. I have posted the requested answers below.

```
result.head(3)

Country    Jan 1    Feb 1   Mar 1   Apr 1   May 1   Jun 1       Quarter_1         Quarter_2 
FRANCE     Yes      Yes      No      No     No       No            2                  0
BELGIUM    Yes      Yes      No     Yes     No       No            2                  1
CANADA     Yes      No       No     Yes     No       No            1                  1
```

I tried the following but `Pandas` spats out a total value instead showing a `5` for all the values under `Quarter_1`. I am oblivious on how to calculate my function below by `Country`? Any assistance with this please!

```
result['Quarter_1'] = len(result[result['Jan 1'] == 'Yes']) + len(result[result['Feb 1'] == 'Yes'])
+ len(result[result['Mar 1'] == 'Yes'])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use the length of your column and take the floor division to create your quarters. Then we groupby on these and take the sum.

Finally to we add the prefix `Quarter`:

```
df = df.set_index('Country')
grps = np.arange(len(df.columns)) // 3
dfn = (
    df.join(df.eq('Yes')
            .groupby(grps, axis=1)
            .sum()
            .astype(int)
            .add_prefix('Quarter_'))
    .reset_index()
)
```

Or using list comprehension to rename your columns:

```
df = df.set_index('Country')
grps = np.arange(len(df.columns)) // 3

dfn = df.eq('Yes').groupby(grps, axis=1).sum().astype(int)
dfn.columns = [f'Quarter_{col+1}' for col in dfn.columns]

df = df.join(dfn).reset_index()
```

```
   Country Jan 1 Feb 1 Mar 1 Apr 1 May 1 Jun 1  Quarter_1  Quarter_2
0   FRANCE   Yes   Yes    No    No    No    No          2          0
1  BELGIUM   Yes   Yes    No   Yes    No    No          2          1
2   CANADA   Yes    No    No   Yes    No    No          1          1
```

Comment: Great answers... I ended up deleting mine after reading yours, was much cleaner :)